# Wordpress. show information in rss

Tags: wordpress

Sorry for noob question. I'm mobile software developer and I haven't seen wordpress dashboard. 
My customer is stuck with such trouble: information that he add to site does not shows in rss. And I can't read this information without rss.
Can you provide photo or video guide how to add some category of information to RSS. 
For now I receive RSS from such adress :  ****.***/feed, .**/visitors/feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. you can get rss by the category of posts.

```
http://example.com/category/categoryname/feed
```

You can view full guide [here](http://example.com/category/categoryname/feed)